# Using newer version of nodejs in a ruby project with cloud foundary

Tags: cloud-foundry

My project is using the latest ruby-buildpack which currently loads nodejs 6.14.4.    I'd like to use a more current version of nodejs.  What's the best way to get it exposed to the application?  Does multi-buildpacks solve this problem, and if so, do I list the nodejs buildpack before or after the ruby buildpack in the manifest file?  Or, would it be better to package a custom buildpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best way to get it exposed to the application? Does multi-buildpacks solve this problem,

I think multi-buildpacks should work for you. You can put Nodejs as a supply buildpack which would tell it to install Node.js, whatever version you want. Then the Ruby buildpack would run and Node.js should be available on the path while it runs so you can use it to do whatever you want.

> and if so, do I list the nodejs buildpack before or after the ruby buildpack in the manifest file

The last buildpack should be the buildpack which supplies the command to start your app. Only the final buildpack is allowed to pick the command which starts your app. Other buildpacks, called supply buildpacks, only contribute/install dependencies.

It sounds like that should be the Ruby buildpack in your case.

> Or, would it be better to package a custom buildpack?

I'd strongly advise against this. Forking and maintaining a buildpack is a lot of work. Let other people do this work for you and you'll be a lot happier :)